# MongoDB/PHP removing a specific array item inside the document

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

Now, I have a document in my collection that I would like to delete on click, and those are comments inside the post document.

Here's the structure:

```
{
    "_id" : "design-patterns-vs-frameworks",
    "title" : "Design Patterns vs Frameworks",
    "category" : [ 
        "Frameworks", 
        " Design Patterns", 
        " PHP"
    ],
    "date_time" : ISODate("2014-09-02T13:45:29.124Z"),
    "description" : "Frameworks vs Design Patterns",
    "content" : " Content!",
    "author" : "Maciej Sitko",
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("54061528af105b51133c986c"),
            "comment" : "ashfklsfsl\r\n",
            "author" : "maciejsitko",
            "date" : ISODate("2014-09-02T19:06:16.646Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5406152caf105b51133c986d"),
            "comment" : "lfasdlfsfl",
            "author" : "maciejsitko",
            "date" : ISODate("2014-09-02T19:06:20.652Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

The full delete link is:

delete.php?post=css-clearfix-explained&id=540617e3af105b8d133c986a
 (as you see two get variables 'post' and 'id')

I tried several solutions,

-First one:

```
$collection->update( array("_id" => $_GET['post']), array( '$unset' => 
 array("comments" => array("_id" => $_GET['id']))) );
```

This one just removed all of my comments inside the comments array.

-Second:

```
$delete = array('$pull' => array("comments" => array( '_id' => $_GET['id'])));
$collection->update(array('_id' => $_GET['post']), $delete);
```

Did not pretty much do anything, strangely enough, this should work, right?

-Third solution:

```
$collection->remove( array('_id' => $_GET['post'], 'comments._id' => $_GET['id']));
```

What would be the proper way of achieving this? I struggled on this one a lot, even implementing some aggregation query and it didn't work out.

Comment: How To add _id To emboded document (comments) in php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove an element from an array you use the [**`$pull`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator. This takes a "query" expression to identify the element you wish to remove:

```
$collection->update( 
    array("_id" => $_GET['post']),
    array( '$pull' => 
        array(
            "comments" => array(
                "_id" => new MongoId( $_GET['id'] )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

The "query" portion of `$pull` acts on the individual elements of the array specified, so anything matching the condition will be removed from the array. But also importantly your request parameter is a "string" so you need to cast this as an actual `ObjectId` value which you can cast in PHP with the [MongoId](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php) class from the driver.

> **NOTE** [Modern driver releases](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/) use [`MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-objectid.php) as the correct method for casting "string hex value" into an actual `ObjectId` representation.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the solution you listed above several times, but forgot to put a new MongoId() indicator, instead, I was just putting there $_GET['id'] in a raw fashion, so it did not pull anything out of the array. Cheers!